# ${} syntax in Serverless

Tags: serverless-framework

On line 19 of [this serverless.yml example](https://github.com/serverless/examples/blob/master/aws-node-rest-api-with-dynamodb/serverless.yml#L10-L19), the following appears:

```
Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"
```

1) Is the syntax `${...}` an instance of bash parameter expansion, like the expansion covered by [this guide](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe)

---

2) In any case, what does the line above do?

Answer (score 1):

Those are variable definitions. They can be defined somewhere else. Example

```
   custom: ${file(env.yml)}

   environment: ${self:custom.environment}
```

Then I define my variables in my env.yml as such

```
environment: dev

Resource: "arn:aws:dynamodb:${opt:region, self:provider.region}:*:table/${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}"
```

that resource is the resource arn for an example DYANMODB_TABLE

You would preform something like this

```
- Sid: "LogsAccess"
                   Effect: "Allow"
                   Action:
                     - "logs:CreateLogGroup"
                     - "logs:CreateLogStream"
                     - "logs:PutLogEvents"
                     - "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
                   Resource: "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
```

But in this case your block would relate to dynamodb.